# Saving a variable data to disk

Tags: c#, .net, xna

Is it possible to save a variable from C# to disk so that you are able to use it later in another  instance of your project?

For example, I have a struct with 3 fields like in the following example :

```
struct MyStruct
{
    byte[] ByteData;
    int MyInt;
    double MyDouble;
};
```

I have an instance of this struct, let's say `MyStruct S` and I assign value to all my fields.
After this step, I would like to save this variable somehow in disk so that I could use those stored values later in my program.

I know, that I could copy those value on a .txt file, but I would like to save the variable as it is on my disk so that I could directly load it into memory during the next runtime of my project.

Is it possible to save it somehow on the disk so that I could load it inside my program as it is?

Comment: Take a look at serialization.

Comment: I would just serialize it to Xml. Then deserialize it back when need it again.

Comment: actually, you *do* want to save it in a textual format. because it will be easier for you to debug. and performance shouldn't really be critical...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public void SerializeObject<T>(string filename, T obj)
   {
      Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
      BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
      stream.Close();
   }

   public T DeSerializeObject<T> (string filename)
   {
      T objectToBeDeSerialized;
      Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
      BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      objectToBeDeSerialized= (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
      stream.Close();
      return objectToBeDeSerialized;
   }

[Serializable]
struct MyStruct
{
    byte[] ByteData;
    int MyInt;
    double MyDouble;
}
```

Do not forget to mark your object as serializable.

Comment: @Archer In fact structs can be serialized using the code, why do you think it is not possible?

Comment: So I create a class which inherits Serializable and I create these two functions to save a file to disk and load it from disk?

Comment: @Simon just add [Serializable] attribute to the class which you want to serialize.

Answer (score 2):

You could use serialization, check this MSDN link, [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The default serialization options is [binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b.aspx) and [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90c86ass.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Serialize it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et91as27.aspx