# Unity Auto Save and loading just a simple variable

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I want to create somehow a statistics scene that shows some information about how much the user interacted with the game

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10230015/2736798) or read about [serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/mt656716.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this inside `OnApplicationFocus` and `OnApplicationPause` function would have been better but there are many instances where these functions are not called and this also depends on the platform. Doing it inside `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` functions should do it because these functions are guaranteed to be called.

Although, you will need to put `DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);` in the Awake function to make sure that `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` are not called when new scene is loading during gameplay.

Problems with your code:

**1**.You are saving `test` key as an int with  `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("test", timesPlayed);` but then loading the `test` key as a float with `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("test")`.

**2**.Even when loading it, you are not assigning the loaded value to anything. `timesPlayed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timesPlayed");` should do it.

**3**.Finally, you are not saving it on exist. Not only this, you are not even calling the `Save()` and `Load()` function from anywhere. You need to [know](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting) what functions gets called when Unity loads and unloads.

Below is a simple **amount of times opened counter** based on your script. Create a GameObject and the script below to it. You can now extend this to include other functions.

```
public class OpenCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    int timesPlayed;
    public Text timeSpendOnGame;

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
        timeSpendOnGame.GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        timeSpendOnGame.text = "" + timesPlayed;
    }


    public void Save()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timesPlayed", timesPlayed);
    }

    //Load
    public void Load()
    {
        timesPlayed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timesPlayed");
    }

    //Load when Opening
    public void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("Opening!");
        Load();
    }

    //Increment and Save on Exit
    public void OnDisable()
    {
        Debug.Log("Existing!");
        timesPlayed++; //Increment how many times opened
        Save(); //save
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo! i came late i actually had it working in a other way but i had an issue with the UI Text it was disappearing in the inspector when im on play mode and i just tried your code it works like a charm! Thx!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I rejected edit because `counter` does not describe anything. `counter` could be anything. `timesPlayed` describes what you asked for in your question.

Comment: Will this work on a android device? The onEnable and onDisable?

Comment: Yes, make simple build and try it. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: How can i do the same thing but for minutes played the game? Im using time.time it's working but acting weird like it gives me 2 minutes and when i run again it gives me 1 minute of gameplay played

Comment: I don't want to use update it will be heavy, im using a coroutine

Comment: I did not use the Update() function in my solution. There is nothing wrong with the Update function. If you have a question about the Update function you can create a new one.